# Facebook Social Plugins / Likebox in German

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins

Is there a way to use the standard facepile social plugin but have it render in German?  I need it to read in German for a site I am finishing, but I don't see anywhere in the documentation that points to any kind of internationalization...  I was thinking I might try to rebuild it in German but I can't apparently make a call to get all the fans for a fan page (you can only check against one user id at a time for me())

Anyone know if there are any language options for the social plugins?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you find something useful there: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization/

Simply said (if you are using JavaScript SDK) you can use the german translated strings if you just integrate their .js in this way:

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js"></script>
```